# How can http://evilsub.domain.com/linkpage.html exist on a webserver even though my host records for domain.com have no entry for "evilsub"?

Tags: javascript, security, github-pages, code-injection, exploit

Google search console has recently let me know that I have a "Hacked: URL injection" security problem. The error message includes links to the pages. These are in the format:

http://weirdsubdomain.example.com/linkpage.html

- I've called this page with curl and wget and the page exists and is returned by the web-server
- My site is hosted at `https://example.com` (note "https")
- My site is a static jekyll site that lives on Github Pages
- The spam/hacking subdomain pages are "http" (not "https")
- My host records on my registrar have no entry for "weirdsubdomain"

I understand I've probably kept an old page with a `<script>` tag in it that most likely pulls in an old version of jquery or that there could well be some old javascript in there somewhere that allows for taking control of people's browers by introducing javascript into a form input of some similar exploit.

What I don't understand, is how it's possible for someone to get DNS to resolve and route a subdomain of my domain? That seems like a server-side thing?

All advice and info very welcome as I set off to try and clean up or disable my javascript:-)

### Update 13 April 2020

I had a look at my host settings and they included records for `*.example.com`.

My understanding is this wildcard configuration lets another Github user apply a subdomain to my domain. I'm not sure if I've understood this properly but if my registrar has a host record that points *.example to the IP address for Github pages, and I have a CNAME file in the root of my repo with "example.com" then another Github user can place a CNAME in their directory with "subdomain.example.com" and the DNS will route requests accordingly.

Is this true? It seems crazy so prob not true:-)

Comment: Does ping resolve to your server or something else?  Are all the nameserver records at your domain registrar correct?  I'd be curious what Google F12 dev tools shows, but you'd want to run that in a VM that you've backed up so you can discard the possibly infected version.  Since it's HTTP you could use wireshark or similar to see what's going on with cURL / wget.

Comment: Hi @DaveS thanks for the response.  I'm not familiar with the Google F12 dev tools (I stopped using Chrome a while back). I haven't gone into the different types of header, setting the agent name to various etc. I had a look at my host settings and they included records for `*.example.com`. I've deleted those records and hoping that kills the routing.